# Using data-attributes to sort items

Tags: javascript, jquery

This function sorts items based on `main categories` and `sub-categories`. The `[data-color]` of the main category is given to the color of the sub-category text if it is `clicked`. 
The code in quotes below shows the part of the code that handles the sub-category button clicks.

The desired behavior of the code is: If you click a `sub-category button` the items show for these sub-categories. If you click it again while it is active, every item is displayed under that main category.

**The problem:** *Sometimes* if you click a `sub-category button` and then click the other one, the items aren't immediately sorted and the `[data-color]` isn't transferred to the `sub-category button`.

If you remove the lines under the note  /*required for unchecking*/ the clicking works fine but double clicking the item doesn't remove the sub-category selection.

How do I get the clicking of `sub-category buttons` to work every time and keep the ability to click a sub-category a second time to remove it's selection by re-working the code in quotations below?

```
$(document).on("click", ".sub-cat-button", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  if ($(this).attr("data-show-main") == "hide") {
    /*required for unchecking*/
    $(".cat-button.focus").trigger("click");
    $(this).attr("data-show-main", "show");
  } else 

  if ($(this).attr("data-show-main") == "show") {
    $(this).attr("data-show-main", "hide");
  } else {
    /*also required for unchecking*/
    $(this).attr("data-show-main", "hide");
  }
});
```

Here is a codepen. The code uses cookies and wouldn't run in a snippet.

https://codepen.io/moofawsaw/pen/jXMPme

Comment: It looks like your inner if else is always setting that attribute to "hide". Why the need of a conditional block?

Comment: Somehow if I remove the second conditional block, I can no longer un-select the sub-cat by clicking it a second time

Comment: sorry what I meant is that your code is 100% equivalent to a simpler: `e.preventDefault();
  if ($(this).attr("data-show-main") == "hide") {
    /*required for unchecking*/
    $(".cat-button.focus").trigger("click");
    $(this).attr("data-show-main", "show");
  } else {
   $(this).attr("data-show-main", "hide");
  }`

Comment: Ok thanks for the cleanup. Do you know about why I am getting the issue from the question? Sometimes when I click between sub-cat buttons the items do not filter

Comment: nope sorry, I didn't even understand what is the issue

Comment: Check out the codepen and click some sub-category buttons and you will see the issue.